# Pulling data from Parse backend and then populating table with it

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, parse-platform

Using: Xcode 8, Swift 3.0

So im currently trying to populate a table by querying the parse server.

This is my current code:

```html
var queryTwo = PFQuery(className:"Agenda")
            queryTwo.whereKey("userEmail", equalTo:"ronadams@gmail.com")
            queryTwo.findObjectsInBackground {
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects {
                    for object in objects {
                        self.timeArray.append(object.object(forKey: "title") as! String)
                        self.titleArray.append(object.object(forKey: "description") as! String)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                self.timeLabel.text = "Error"
            }
        }
```

Why is no information being added to the array? My database has 2 entries for that email. But nothing is even being added to the arrays, even though the query is succeeding.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are your UITableViewDataSource methods?

Comment: and where is your tableView.reloadData() function....

Comment: did you double check the spelling? It's a common error